# Uncaught Oauth Exception

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ip, whitelist

I have a php application calling the Graph API. It's been working for almost a year and stopped working today with the following error:

Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: This IP can't make requests for that application. thrown in /mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/nn-6-38e7eee3a80186c674057d8c08ede661/app/vendor/facebook/php-sdk/src/base_facebook.php on line 1133

The server is through appfog and the hostname is: nn.aws.af.cm

I've looked through posts suggesting that I add the IP to a whitelist. This did not solve the problem. (54.236.159.122)

I'd appreciate it if someone could provide the correct answer. Thanks in advance for your time.